# Can I reduce my simulation error with a staggered grid, postprocessing and compatibility equation feedback?

Tags: finite-difference, simulation, error-estimation, hyperbolic-pde, grid

**What I did**

Using the finite difference method, I solved with a certain amount of error the following system of hyperbolic partial differential equations in cylindrical coordinates (the problem is axisymmetric, so the angular coordinate is not used):

$$ {\partial ^2 u \over \partial r^2} + {1 \over r}{\partial u \over \partial r} +{\partial ^2 u \over \partial z^2}-f={1\over c^2}{\partial ^2 u \over \partial t^2} \tag 1$$

$$ {\partial ^2 f \over \partial r^2} + {1 \over r}{\partial f \over \partial r} +{\partial ^2 f \over \partial z^2}={\partial ^2 f \over \partial t^2} \tag 2$$

$$ {\partial ^2 v \over \partial r^2} + {1 \over r}{\partial v \over \partial r} -{1\over r^2}v+c^2{\partial ^2 v \over \partial z^2}+\big(1-c^2\big){\partial ^3 u \over \partial r\partial z^2}={\partial ^2 v \over \partial t^2} \tag 3$$

where $c$ is a constant. The initial conditions are the following:

$$u(r,z,0)=f(r,z,0)=v(r,z,0)=0 \tag 4$$

$${\partial u \over \partial t} \Bigg |_{t=0} = u_0 \ \mathrm{if} \ z = 0 \tag 5$$
$${\partial u \over \partial t} \Bigg |_{t=0} = 0 \ \mathrm{if} \ z > 0 \tag 6$$
$${\partial f \over \partial t} \Bigg |_{t=0} = f_0 \ \mathrm{if} \ z = 0 \tag 7$$
$${\partial f \over \partial t} \Bigg |_{t=0} = 0 \ \mathrm{if} \ z > 0 \tag 8$$
$${\partial v \over \partial t} \Bigg |_{t=0} = 0 \tag 9$$

At $z = 1$, I have zero boundary conditions:

$$u(r,1,t)=f(r,1,t)=v(r,1,t)=0 \tag {10}$$

Also, I have the following zero boundary conditions at the axis:

$$ {\partial u \over \partial r} \Bigg |_{r=0}={\partial f \over \partial r} \Bigg |_{r=0} = v(0,z,t) = 0 \tag {11}$$

Note that instead of equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ which contain singularities, the following two equations can be used at the axis:

$$ 2{\partial ^2 u \over \partial r^2} + {\partial ^2 u \over \partial z^2}-f={1\over c^2}{\partial ^2 u \over \partial t^2} \tag {12}$$

$$ 2{\partial ^2 f \over \partial r^2} + {\partial ^2 f \over \partial z^2}={\partial ^2 f \over \partial t^2} \tag {13}$$

The boundary conditions $r=r_{max}$ are the following:

$${\partial u \over \partial r} \Bigg |_{r=r_{max}}=-v(r_{max},z,t) \tag {10}$$
$${\partial v \over \partial r} \Bigg |_{r=r_{max}}={2c^2-1 \over 2\big(c^2-1\big)}f(r_{max},z,t) \tag {14}$$

$$ {\partial f \over \partial r} \Bigg |_{r=r_{max}} + {1-2c^2 \over 2c^2}{1\over r_{max}}f(r_{max},z,t)= {c^2-1 \over c^2} \Bigg(
{\partial ^2 v \over \partial r^2}\Bigg |_{r=r_{max}}-{1\over r_{max}^2}v(r_{max},z,t)-{\partial ^2 v \over \partial z^2}\Bigg |_{r=r_{max}} \Bigg) \tag {15}$$

At $z = 0$, I have the following boundary conditions:

$$ {\partial f \over \partial z} \Bigg |_{z=0} = v(r,0,t)=0 \tag {16}$$

$${\partial u \over \partial z} \Bigg |_{z=0} = kf(r,0,t) \tag {17}$$

where $k$ is a constant.

**The problem**

Even though my solution is stable in the sense that the simulation error didn't grow unbounded, the function $v$ has a spike at $r_{max}$ at the beginning of the simulation. This is caused mainly because of the corner boundary condition inconsistency at $(r=r_{max}, z=0)$. This spike introduces the error I am trying to minimize. Below are the graphs of $v$ at three different time steps that illustrate the problem.

[image: P1]
[image: P2]
[image: P3]

**Staggered grid questions**

Can I use a staggered spatial grid and a collocated temporal grid to reduce this error? Currently, I am not using one. However, the function $v$ is zero at $z=0$ and $z=1$, so it might be convenient to use one. The problem is, I'm not sure how I should construct one. I am thinking of using the same cells for calculating $u$ and $f$, just like one would calculate the pressure in the Lid-driven cavity problem, and just shift the grid by half a cell for calculating the $v$ function. However, I don't know if I should shift $v$ in the radial or longitudinal direction. I am hoping somebody can clarify this to me.

**Postprocessing questions**

Can I use some postprocessing techniques to recover my functions from the errors? If yes, which ones and how? Note that I have the following compatibility equation I can use, which is not used in the current solver I wrote:

$$f={c^2 - 1\over c^2} \Bigg( {\partial ^2 u \over \partial z^2} + {\partial v \over \partial r} + {1 \over r}v\Bigg)  \tag {18}$$

Can I use this equation to evaluate the error and somehow reduce it in postprocessing?

**Feedback question**

Can I use the compatibility equation $(18)$ as feedback to reduce the simulation error during the solution loop? If yes, how? Note that I am using a 7-point stencil.

Comment: What is the physics behind this? Some kind of shockwave in a spherical confinement?:-)

Comment: It actually models an impact problem between cylinders :D

Comment: Ahh. Makes sense.